# Generating a 3D surface based on some coordinates and randomly distribute points on it with R

Tags: r, distribution, surface, points, plot3d

I have a dataset (`df`) containing a long list of points (each with its own x, y, z coordinates). These points sit on a 3D shape that is roughly rectangular. The surface is derived from image segmentation.

I am trying to assess their spatial distribution. If they cluster, etc. As a control I want to generate an empty surface spanning a similar area and place random dots on it.

to obtain an area of similar size I am extracting the lower and upper limits in the 3 dimensions

```
x <- (range(as.numeric(df$x)))
y <- (range(as.numeric(df$y)))
z <- (range(as.numeric(df$z)))
```

These give me two values for each variable. e.g x[0,2], y[3,5], z[6,18]
I then try to feed these to plot3D library and `surf3D()` function

```
  library(plot3D)
  surf3D (x=x, y=y, z=z, phi = 40, theta = 40,
    col = NULL, NAcol = "white", breaks = NULL,
    border = NA, facets = TRUE, colkey = NULL,
    panel.first = NULL, clim = NULL, clab = NULL, bty = "n",
    lighting = FALSE, shade = NA, ltheta = -135, lphi = 0,
    inttype = 1, add = FALSE, plot = TRUE)
```

I start getting errors here. The aim is to generate something like [this](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&biw=1366&bih=609&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=80TaWv-qI-iVgAbf6YmABg&q=rectangle+in+3d+space&oq=rectangle+in+3d+space&gs_l=psy-ab.3...79172.81469.0.82306.4.4.0.0.0.0.97.331.4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.lci6efvoXMI#imgrc=px8mKpgcMU8pZM:&spf=1524254024623).

I ultimately wanted to generate an equivalent number of points within the polygon using.

```
   library(splancs)
   csr(poly,npoints)
```

(This function requires a polygon to start with.)
(https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2005-September/000567.html)

Could someone give me a hand with the rectangle generation?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. Look at the help page for `?range`. You are sending 3 length-2 vectors to surf3D and expecting a surface?

Comment: I know that the output of range will be 2 values (lower and upper limits). My aim is to generate a rectangle in 3d space

https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&biw=1366&bih=609&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=80TaWv-qI-iVgAbf6YmABg&q=rectangle+in+3d+space&oq=rectangle+in+3d+space&gs_l=psy-ab.3...79172.81469.0.82306.4.4.0.0.0.0.97.331.4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.lci6efvoXMI#imgrc=px8mKpgcMU8pZM:&spf=1524254024623 like this

Comment: You need 4 vectors each with an x,y and z value for an arbitrary rectangle. You may have difficulties if they are not coplanar. I don't that is being offered with your call. The equivalent of a "bounding rectangle in 2-space" in 3-space is a box with sides that are variously coplanar with the xy, xz and yz axis planes.

Comment: Do you know, in terms of code, how I would generate the surface from the 4 points? I can manually create the four points from the x,y,z limits that I get from range so that would be ok

Comment: I guess the answer s that I don't yet know. But ... What 4 points? I tried to explain that you had neither given us 4 points, nor were 4 points defined by the problem description. Have you worked through the examples on the surf3D help page?